# New iptables rules only affect new spawned process

Tags: iptables

Is there a way to update iptables rules to block a connexion without the need of restarting it?

Here is an example of the behavior I want to avoid:

```
On shell#1: I start a ping command 8.8.8.8
On shell#2: I block ping command with iptables rules.
On shell#1: The ping command is still working and I get replies from 8.8.8.8, 
            but if I end the ping command and I restart it, now it will not work.
```

I would like to know if there is a way to block the ping command without the need of restarting it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) What you ask is the simplest way for `iptables` to work - block all traffic to a destination regardless of connection status, so that existing connections will time out.  So in your example

```
iptables -I OUTPUT -d 8.8.8.8 -j DROP
```

will immediately block UDP (DNS), ICMP (ping) and TCP packets reaching 8.8.8.8.  So that seems to be your answer.  If you are getting the behaviour you describe, post the iptables command line you are using.

2) If you did want the other behaviour, to maintain existing connections until the process is restarted, you could either:

```
iptables -I OUTPUT -d 8.8.8.8 -m state --state NEW -j DROP
```

or

```
iptables -I OUTPUT -d 8.8.8.8 -p tcp --syn -j REJECT
```

3) In the advanced case where you want to actually close an established TCP connection as soon as possible rather than block it and let it time out, you could maybe base something on `-j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset` in the input and output chains or run `tcpkill` for a few seconds.  This is difficult, and in almost all cases, you want to break the connection with solution 1).

Comment: I think this is Cedric's way of saying that you're probably confusing the issue with a permit on `ESTABLISHED` traffic that's allowing the pre-existing PING.  As he says, if step (1) doesn't stop the traffic immediately, something really is wrong, and we'd like to see the output of `iptables -L -n -v`.  +1 from me, Cedric.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, simplification and paraphrase.  Exactly so.  I'm just not sure if Fvaliquette has tried it and is seeing residual traffic or is just theorising.